# How to download a pre-updated Steam

Tags: steam

After installing Steam, it demanded an update of 127 MB. But I don't have an Internet connection. So can I download a pre-updated Steam from any other computer which has an Internet connection?

Comment: You should be able to. Just copy the files over... But as for what files: I don't know.

Comment: You need to start a game once while connected to the steam servers bevore you can play it in offline mode. So even if you manage to install Steam on a computer not connected to the internet at all wouldn't help you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you can do it by copying the whole Steam repository from another computer where steam is fully installed as @aytimothy said and as it is explained here : http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/828934913076877521/

If you copy it from a friend or so, copy everything except the SteamApps repository because it contains the games.

But steam is constantly updated and is really thought to be used with an internet connection.

Comment: ... Please cite the answer from the page **put it into your post**. We don't allow link-only answers.

Comment: Simply to put it: "What files to copy?"